# SAS Token auth for azure eventhub with amqp.net lite

Tags: c#, azure, mono, amqp, azure-eventhub

I am currently using [amqp.net lite](https://amqpnetlite.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20Amqp.Net%20Lite%20with%20Azure%20Server%20Bus%20Event%20Hub&referringTitle=Documentation) with mono for sending messages to azure eventhub from my raspberry pi.

My connection string looks like this: *amqps://SendMessage:[url encoded key]@[sb namespace]*

This works fine but now I want to use SAS tokens instead. 
What would a valid connection string look like in this case?
Nothing I tried worked for me so far.

P.S. I am not using the official NuGet Package from Microsoft because it doesn't work on mono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the mechanism described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-sas-overview/) does work. Read the last section titled "Using the Shared Access Signature (at AMQP level)". It describes how to use SAS tokens with [Amqp.NET Lite](http://amqpnetlite.codeplex.com/) which is pretty low level. Use [Azure SB Lite](https://github.com/ppatierno/azuresblite) for more simplicity. It is still based on Amqp.NET Lite but offers more abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

amqps://[SharedAccessKeyName]:[url encoded SharedAccessKey]@[sb namespace]

SharedAccessKeyName and SharedAccessKey is policy name and token that these get from portal.

```
        string eventhubHostFormat = "amqps://{0}:{1}@{2}.servicebus.windows.net";

        var address = new Address(string.Format(eventhubHostFormat, "your SAS policy name", Uri.EscapeUriString("your SAS key"), "your servicebus name"));
        var eventHubConnection = new Connection(address);
        var eventHubSession = new Session(eventHubConnection);
        var eventHubSender = new SenderLink(eventHubSession, "0" /* partition ID */, "your eventhub name");
```

Comment: Thanks but as I said I need to use SAS tokens not the SAS key, there is a difference

Comment: OH. Sorry, I was understood now.

Comment: We can create the SAS token, But..
What do I use to resourceURI for SAS token?
How to use SAS token?

I tried many pattern. But I doesn't success..

Comment: Yes exactly, the transfer of this token is a problem. I tried many things myself too but without success. I am going to contact Microsoft on this issue and let u know the outcome.